# How to put conditions in loop statements

Tags: java

This program is to take input from the user and to give output back showing how many numbers were above the average of the array and below it. I'm trying to put a condition on the loops to exit getting input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class analyzeScores {

    public static void count(int[] list) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length;i++) {
            if(list[i] != 0)
                list[i] = input.nextInt();

        }
    }


    public static void sorts(int[] lists, int average) {
        int high = 0;
        int low = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
            if(lists[i] >= average) {
                high +=1;
            }
            else {
                low += 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The number of higher then average scores    is " + high);
        System.out.println("The number of lower then average scores is " + low);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] list = new int[10];
        System.out.println("Enter the scores: ");
        count(list);
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length;i++) {
            total += list[i];
        }
        total = total / list.length;
        sorts(list, total);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a way to input 0 to exit the loop in the count(int[] list) method. I tried to implement if(list[i] != 0) but messes the whole code up

Comment: This has been answered on SO in the past. You can search for the answer. Also, look into while loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to add an else condition to your if statement in the loop,
This should work if the rest of your code works

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class analyzeScores {
    public static void count(int[] list) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length;i++) {
            if(list[i] != 0){
                list[i] = input.nextInt();
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    public static void sorts(int[] lists, int average) {
        int high = 0;
        int low = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
            if(lists[i] >= average) {
                high +=1;
            }
            else {
                low += 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The number of higher then average scores    is " + high);
        System.out.println("The number of lower then average scores is " + low);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] list = new int[10];
        System.out.println("Enter the scores: ");
        count(list);
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length;i++) {
            total += list[i];
        }
        total = total / list.length;
        sorts(list, total);
    }
}
```